# How can I check my post data in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework

I am a beginner and I am creating some forms to be posted into MySQL using Zend, and I am in the process of debugging but I don't really know how to debug anything using Zend. I want to submit the form and see if my custom forms are concatenating the data properly before it goes into MySQL, so I want to catch the post data to see a few things. How can I do this?

Comment: Consider using an IDE supporting XDebug or Zend Debugger (depending on what you can / have installed on your development server).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Default route for zend framework application looks like the following

```
http://www.name.tld/$controller/$action/$param1/$value1/.../$paramX/$valueX
```

So all $_GET-Parameters simply get contenated onto the url in the above manner `/param/value`

Let's say you are within `IndexController` and `indexAction()` in here you call a form. Now there's possible two things happening:

1. You do not define a Form-Action, then you will send the form back to `IndexController:indexAction()`
2. You define a Form action via `$form->setAction('/index/process')` in that case you would end up at `IndexController:processAction()`

The way to access the Params is already defined above. Whereas `$this->_getParam()` equals `$this->getRequest()->getParam()` and `$this->_getAllParams()` equals `$this->getRequest->getParams()`

The right way yo check data of Zend Stuff is using Zend_Debug as [@vascowhite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212940/vascowhite) has pointed out. If you want to see the final Query-String (in case you're manually building queries), then you can simply put in the insert variable into Zend_Debug::dump()

Answer (score 3):

you can use `$this->_getAllParams();`.

For example: `var_dump($this->_getAllParams()); die;` will output all the parameters ZF received and halt the execution of the script. To be used in your receiving Action.

Also, `$this->_getParam("param name");` will get a specific parameter from the request.

Comment: I am unsure as to which action is my receiving action. How can I figure this out? I pretty much am doing the samething as the quickstart tutorial except with MySQL. In that regards, I am not sure what happens after I hit submit for the form. I think it goes back into its controller, but I don't know where does it go from there.

Comment: Oh, I see, so I put it in the action that called the form, but feel free to answer my question still!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to check variables in Zend Framework is to use `Zend_Debug::dump($variable);` so you can do this:-

```
Zend_Debug::dump($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Zend framework is built on the top of the PHP . so you can use var_dump($_POST) to check the post variables.

ZF has provided its own functions to get  all the post variables.. Zend_Debug::dump($this->getRequest()->getPost())

or specifically for one variable.. you can use Zend_Debug::dump($this->getRequest()->getPost($key))

Answer (score 0):

You can check post data by using zend

$request->isPost()

and for retrieving post data

$request->getPost()

For example

if ($request->isPost()) {

```
$postData = $request->getPost();

Zend_Debug::dump($postData );
```

}